# How can i get the stack trace just before a redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a fairly complex page model. On one of my pages I have fixed a bug. This page then redirects to another page but I dont know where this redirection is happening in the page model?. The navigation is kept in a db so I cant search for the response.Reddirect in the c# etc....

Is there a place where I can set a breakpoint so that it will stop the app just before the redirect happens and then I can look through the stack trace to see what methods are getting called in the lifecycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

    public class Program
    {   
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test43545();
            Test1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Test43545(){
            Test1();
        }
        public static void Test1()
        {
            StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();    
            StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();

            // write call stack method names
            foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above will get you the names of the functions which were called, up to calling `Test1()`. This will tell you which methods were called before the redirect (hopefully :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve what you need by [Code Stepping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ek13f001.aspx). Set a breakpoint at the latest line on the page which you know will definitely execute, and then press F11 to go through the code line by line.